# LINQ With Group By And rownum

Tags: c#, linq, oracle

I have a Oracle SQL Query like below and want LINQ equal.

```
SELECT ROWNUM rn, 
       tmp.* 
FROM   (SELECT tbl.name, 
               SUM(tbl.debit) 
        FROM   table1 tbl 
        GROUP  BY tbl.name)
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like that, using the overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb534638.aspx) using an `index`.

Here, `rn` represents this `index`, which is... a row number.

```
var result = <someWayToGetTable1>.GroupBy(m => m.Name)
.Select(m => new {
   name = m.Key,
   allDebit = m.Sum(x => x.debit),
})
.ToList()
.Select((m, rn) => new {
    m.name,
    m.allDebit,
    rn
});
```

version with partially non fluent syntax

```
 var queryable= from item in <Table1>
                 group item by item.name into g
                 select new {
                    name =m.Key,
                    allDebit = m.Sum(x => x.debit
                 }
   var result = queryable.ToList()
                 .Select((g, rn) => new {
                      g.name,
                      g.allDebit
                      rn
                  });
```

Comment: plz answer in not chaining method.

Comment: Is select with `Expression<Func<TSource, int, TResult>` parameter supported by oracle linq provider?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Must admit I'm not sure about that point. For ehsan, see waht you can do. Not all can be done with non fluent syntax (as far as i know).

Comment: I try 
            var model =
                (_db2.Persons.Select((x, index) => new
                {
                    rn = index + 1,
                    col1 = x.Id
                })).ToList();
but now, i have this error:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1 method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @ehsan see "edited second version". Seems that with Oracle, you can't do that at db level, so you need to enumerate first...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
YourDataContext.tbls.GroupBy(a => a.name)
.select((a, index) => new
{
    rn = index,
    name = a.Key,
    debitSum = a.Sum(b => b.debit)
});
```

Comment: I try var model = (_db2.Persons.Select((x, index) => new { rn = index + 1, col1 = x.Id })).ToList(); but now, i have this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1 method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.